# Show that $\bf x$ is a basic feasible solution

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider the standard form polyhedron

$${\mathsf P} := \left\{ {\bf x} \in {\Bbb R}^n \mid {\bf A} {\bf x} = {\bf b}, {\bf x} \ge {\bf 0}_n \right\}.$$

Suppose that the $m \times n$ matrix $\bf A$ has  linearly  independent rows,  and that all basic feasible solutions  are non-degenerate. Let $\bf x \in \mathsf P$ have exactly $m$ positive  components. Show that $\bf x$ is a basic  feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** If $x$ is a basic feasible solution, then the columns corresponding to the nonzero components of $x$ must be linearly independent (why?). What would happen if that was not the case?

**Hint 2:** How does the assumption on linearly independent rows help you? Arguing by contradiction, can you use it to construct a basis which would lead to a degenerate solution? Clearly, you would have to modify $x$ and the corresponding columns of $A$ somehow.

If none of these hints help, you can find the last resort solution [here](https://math.solverer.com/library/dimitris_bertsimas/introduction_to_linear_optimization/exercise_2-13?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link).